# How do I configure a proxy for lwp-download?

Tags: perl

When I try  to get a file from somewhere Internet, for example ,http::/www.aaa.com/bbb.tar, everything goes smoothly. When I use lwp-download to get the same file,  the app just hangs.

After some troubleshooting, I realized that it is because a proxy has been set for Firefox that makes it work.

How do I configure an HTTP proxy for lwp-download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lwp-download uses the [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.831/lib/LWP.pm) Perl package, which can use [environment variables](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.831/lib/LWP.pm#ENVIRONMENT) for setting up proxies. You could try setting the HTTP_PROXY environment variable to your proxy address...

Failing that, switch to something else, like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/), which supports [setting a proxy directly](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-x--proxy).